# Constraints not working in TableViewCell

Tags: ios, uitableview, cell

I'm learning how to use CoreData to store images, and I'm making a blog reader. I have a view That shows all the info saved as a list and when you click it takes you to that article. My problem is that I can't make TableViewCells look as intended. I have added the constraints and not a single of them is being placed.

Here are my constraints: 
[image]

And this is the result:
[image]

I've deleted them, cleaned, closed xCode, put them again and the same result. Found [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43319921/autolayout-is-ignored-in-custom-uitableviewcell), checked and nothing. Also [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19015215/trouble-with-autolayout-on-uitableviewcell). In the same project, I have another TableView and it works fine, any ideas why this is happening? Thanks a lot!

Comment: UIImageView has fixed width and height constraints??

Comment: Yes, 90x108 pixels

Comment: @Enrique Set image view constraints to -: Leading,Top,Height,Width. And for label try set -: Leading,top,trailing,height.Check after that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like image is overflowing form the container. Try this

1. Set the UIImageView content mode to `UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFill`
2. Set UIImageView `clipToBounds` to true.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like issue not because of constraints. it because of image to solution for this issue

You have two option to solve this

**1) Via code**

```
cell.YOUR_IMAGE_VIEW.clipsToBounds = true
```

**2) Via Interface Builder**

[image]

*Hope this will help you*

Comment: Please stop adding *Thanks in advance* in suggested edits. Those have no place in posts here, see https://stackoverflow.com/help/behavior: *Do not use signature, taglines, or greetings.*. You are making extra work for others having to remove those again.