# Constraints ignored in custom tableview cell

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

I was trying to design a custom cell for UItableView, but for some unknown reasons the constraints that I set for the elements inside were ignored. In fact, I don't even know why the elements were arranged in the ways they did.

It looks like this in IB:

[image: It looks like this in IB]

Details:

[image: Details]

But somehow it appears like this:

[image: But somehow it appears like this.]

Comment: Have a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49142143/adding-constraints-to-uitableviewcell/49145481

Comment: Add your code work also.

Answer (score 2):

You should either

**X) Turn on auto height for TableView**

[image]

**Y) Or, implement this delegate method**

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {
    return UITableView.automaticDimension
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, estimatedHeightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {
    return UITableView.automaticDimension
}
```