# Auto layout fails in UITableViewCell

Tags: xcode, uitableview, autolayout, constraints

My constraints are not working inside a UITableViewCell, although there are no warnings and the layout is working in interface builder if I change between devices and do rotation.

What did I do:

I created a UITableViewCell called SearchResultCell. I want to layout a button on the right hand side and two labels on the left and the labels should horizontally fill the entire space until the button.

Initially, I just placed the views there and - no matter which constraints I defined - in the simulator all views always appeared at the top left corner.

Then I tried embedding them into stack views. The two labels into a vertical stack view which I then put together with the button into a horizontal stack view. Then I defined constraints such that the outmost stack view should fill the entire superview, i.e. I set bottom, trailing, top, and leading constraints to 0.

[My constraints](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HpnrV.png)

Again, in interface builder it is always shown correctly:

[Layout works correctly in interface builder](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UtmTE.png)

However, once launched, these constraints do not seem to be applied.

[How it looks like in simulator](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uvY32.png)

The only (slight) improvement is that now the button is beside the label thanks to the stack view. But no matter what I try, I cannot get the constraints working inside this UITableViewCell.

What am I doing wrong here? I don't see it.

Comment: It sounds like you're doing what you need to do... Are you sure you're referencing the correct cell class in cellForRowAt?

Comment: I am using dequeueReusableCell with the correct identifier.

Comment: Take a look at: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18746929/using-auto-layout-in-uitableview-for-dynamic-cell-layouts-variable-row-heights. It has very detailed answer for using dynamic(self-sizing) cells.

Comment: I read that article. Luckily, I do not need self-sizing cells because all cells in my table view will have identical layout and hence the same row height. Another key point is: "don't pin subviews to the cell itself; only to the cell's contentView" - which is exactly what I did, I verified it. So the last thing I could do was to follow the recommendation to "set up your constraints in code", and I did that too by overriding updateConstraints(), still the behavior does not change. I cannot get the stack view to fill the entire content view of my UITableViewCell.

Answer (score 0):

Did a lot of more digging and finally came across this - indeed, it was my problem as well: [Autolayout is ignored in Custom UITableViewCell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43319921/autolayout-is-ignored-in-custom-uitableviewcell)