# Wrong disposition of contents of custom UITableViewCell

Tags: swift, uitableview, autolayout, xcode-storyboard

I have a custom UITableViewCell (with .xib file and custom class inherit from UITableViewCell, which have four labels). I have implemented the constraints of the contents properly, and this is the aspect in storyboard.

[image]

But when I run the app in simulator, the result is this.

[image]

It seems the contents goes to point 0,0 of x,y axis, but I can't figure out what happens.

I tried [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43319921/autolayout-is-ignored-in-custom-uitableviewcell), but doesn't work for me.

My app is made with storyboard. I have, in a ViewController, a UITableView (default) and I created a UITableViewCell customized (called StatementTableViewCell), which I register via code inside viewDidLoad's viewController method (tableView.registerNib(.....)).

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        // I've put the name of identifier and the class as the same.        
        self.tableView.register(UINib(nibName: IDENTIFIERS.TABLE_VIEW_CELL, bundle: nil), forCellReuseIdentifier: IDENTIFIERS.TABLE_VIEW_CELL)
        
        // remainded code
    }
```

Someone knows how to solve this and please could help me? Thanks!

Comment: Can you reduce the example to just this table and post it to GitHub?

Comment: Did you change the class of the cell's `Content View`? If so, that's a no-no.

Comment: @matt Sure! I've created a sample project based on the same logic. But now the contents are all right-aligned. Here you go: https://github.com/AdrianoAntoniev/PreferredBands

Comment: Cool, let me take a look for you.

Comment: @DonMag, yes, I changed it. Very strange

Comment: Unfortunately I can't run this because you removed the Info.plist.

Comment: I made the upload from Xcode. Sorry, I will upload the info.plist

Comment: @matt now I uploaded the info.plist. I really appreciate if you would take a loot, if you can. Thanks and sorry for my mistake

Comment: OK well it looks pretty good. The four labels are in the four corners. They are truncated with ellipses, but that's to be expected. What did you want to have happen?

Comment: @adrianoingo - I grabbed your GitHub project... except for the fact that your horizontal stack view has `Spacing: 255` (you probably want that to be `8`), it works fine.

Comment: @matt when I run the code, instead of have the info of the bands, the labels are all in the right side of the screen, showing just the two labels of left.

Comment: @DonMag I will look at this, thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, well, you didn't tell the truth in your question about how this is laid out. You have two vertical stack views inside a horizontal stack view. So:

- Change the outer stack view's distribution to Fill Equally and zero spacing (or maybe 8, as Don Mag suggests).
- Change the labels' number of lines to 0.

Bingo. You do still have some ambiguity issues due to the content hugging of the labels, but you can take care of that later.

[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot @matt, it solved my problem! Thanks for you and @DonMag!

Comment: You were almost there. :)